# WeakEventManager not handling interfaces correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to use the `WeakEventManager` to - well - use weak events. As source type I am using an interface and that is causing a problem. See code sample below.

When I start the program as is, it errors when calling `WeakEventManager` (last statement, see comment "here's the error"). It says, there is no `PropertyChanged` event on `IMyEventSource`. I then thought to add `event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` to `IMyEventSource`. That indeed fixes the issue but leaves me with the warning that my event declaration in the interface would hide the inherited member. Which makes sense as `IMyEventSource` says it would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It's feels like catch-22.

Obviously I can accept the warning and add new to the event declaration. But I hope someone can tell me how to do better.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyEventSource source = new MyEventSource();
        WeakEventListener listener = new WeakEventListener(source);
        source.Name = "John Dow";
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IMyEventSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;   // fixes the issue
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyEventSource : IMyEventSource
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set { name = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); ; }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class WeakEventListener
{
    private void OnEvent(object source, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) => Console.WriteLine("WeakEventListener received event.");

    public WeakEventListener(MyEventSource source)
    {
        WeakEventManager<IMyEventSource, PropertyChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(source, "PropertyChanged", OnEvent); // here's the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `WeakEventManager<INotifyPropertyChanged, PropertyChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(source, "PropertyChanged", OnEvent);`?

Comment: There's a specific manager for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you Klaus. Works. And thanks Andy for pointing me to